# Jackson Custom Deserializer/Serializer with Spring MongoTemplates

Tags: spring, mongodb, serialization, deserialization

I am having trouble accessing and writing data from/to mongoDB using spring mongoTemplate.

For starters I have a data-model that represents the object that I am trying to retrieve from mongo. I have it annotated with @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize for specifying custom converters.

However when I invoke mongoTemplate.findById(), and try to get this object, I find that my custom deserializer is not invoked at all and I get HttpMessageNotWriteableException.

Is there any other configuration that must be put in place to let mongo know that it needs to use my custom Jackson deserializer?

Comment: Can you provide more information like dependencies that you are using and any configuration you are doing for json serialization/deserialization?

Comment: @ritesh.garg All I have done is to annotate my datamodel with @ JsonSerializer and @ JsonDeserializer. I have not done ANY mongo related config yet. But looking at the docs through, I dont think there is a way to replace MongoConverters with Jackson Serializers/Deserializers. Can we let Jackson do the conversion instead of spring/mongo combo?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for reference: https://gist.github.com/letalvoj/978e6c975398693fc6843c5fe648416d

Comment: Great find thanks for that, but is there a way to just register JSON serializer/deserializers? That way I dont have to redo all the work again.